# Apply regex on columns using awk

Tags: regex, shell, awk

I have the following string that I get:

```
 new Field("count").del("query_then_fetch");
 new Field("scan").del("query_then_fetch sorting on `_doc`");
 new Field("compress").del("no replacement, implemented at the codec level");
 new Field("compress_threshold").del("no replacement");
 new Field("filter").del("query");
```

I run the following script on command line where the regex matches the strings that are in double quotes.:

```
awk -F '.del' '{match($1, "\".*\"", a); match($2, "\".*\"", b)}END{print a[0]; print b[0]}'
```

expecting this king of output:

```
"count" "query_then_fetch"
"scan" "query_then_fetch sorting on `_doc`"
"compress" "no replacement, implemented at the codec level"
"compress_threshold" "no replacement"
"filter" "query"
```

but instead I get this output:

```
"filter"
"query"
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: This matches what you need better `\"[^\"]*\"` (so matches a quotation mark then anything not a quotation mark then a quotation mark)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cat sample.csv                                    
 new Field("count").del("query_then_fetch");
 new Field("scan").del("query_then_fetch sorting on `_doc`");
 new Field("compress").del("no replacement, implemented at the codec level");
 new Field("compress_threshold").del("no replacement");
 new Field("filter").del("query");

awk -F'"' -v q="\"" '{print q $2 q,q $4 q}' sample.csv  
"count" "query_then_fetch"
"scan" "query_then_fetch sorting on `_doc`"
"compress" "no replacement, implemented at the codec level"
"compress_threshold" "no replacement"
"filter" "query"
```

I am using double quotes as field separator and print out the 2nd and 4th fields

Answer (score 1):

Your `awk` script is only printing **once** during the `END` block at the end of processing all the input.

At which point you are printing `a[0]` and `b[0]` on separate lines (because you are using two `print` statements).

What you want, with your current `awk` script, is to print `a[0]` and `b[0]` in a single `printf` statement *while* processing each line.

```
awk -F '.del' '{match($1, "\".*\"", a); match($2, "\".*\"", b); printf "%s %s\n",a[0], b[0]}' sample.csv
```

Alternatively you could use the much simpler `awk` script below which splits the input on `(` and `)` characters.

```
awk -F '[()]' '{print $2,$4}' sample.csv
```

Comment: `[()]` is not GNU specific... +1

Comment: @dawg Fair enough. I couldn't recall whether a regex `FS` value was a GNU-ism or not (and was too lazy to go check the docs/spec the way I just did). Thanks.

Comment: It's just a regex `RS` value that's a GNU-ism, all awks have always supported a regex `FS` (well, not EXACTLY a regexp but very close in all important ways). All POSIX awks just use the first char of whatever string you set `RS` to as the record separator.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
$ echo "$tgt" 
 new Field("count").del("query_then_fetch");
 new Field("scan").del("query_then_fetch sorting on `_doc`");
 new Field("compress").del("no replacement, implemented at the codec level");
 new Field("compress_threshold").del("no replacement");
 new Field("filter").del("query");
```

You can do:

```
$ echo "$tgt" | awk  '{split($0, a, "\""); print a[2]"\t"a[4]}'
count   query_then_fetch
scan    query_then_fetch sorting on `_doc`
compress    no replacement, implemented at the codec level
compress_threshold  no replacement
filter  query
```

Add quotes around the fields as needed.

Or, you can do:

```
$ echo "$tgt" | awk  '{split($0, a, /[()]/); print a[2],a[4]}'
"count" "query_then_fetch"
"scan" "query_then_fetch sorting on `_doc`"
"compress" "no replacement, implemented at the codec level"
"compress_threshold" "no replacement"
"filter" "query"
```